# .htaccess Rewrite with multiple rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to update my .htaccess to handle rewrite of URL in following format.

rewriting this url:
`/score.php?state=FL&name=somename&id=123`
to
`/FL/somename-event/123-event`

and also this rewrite rule:
`/state.php?state=FL`
to
`/FL`

I have the following but it generates a 500 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-event$ /score.php?state=$1&name=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /state.php?state=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `*` to match 1+ characters in your regex and ignore all files and directories from your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ state.php?state=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)-event$ score.php?state=$1&name=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```